# Does Zend_PDF module support hyphenation?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf-generation, itext, hyphenation

I'm looking for iTextSharp like [auto hyphenation](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/PDF/iTextSharp/iTextSharp/text/pdf/HyphenationAuto.cs.htm) support in creating PDF. I couldn't find anything related in Zend Docs.

**Edit** I also Googled if this class was ported in PHP but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is NO. Zend_Pdf is not known to be one of the highly evolved components of the framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for that in the current version of Zend_PDF. I do not know of any library that do this in PHP.

Comment: There is no free PHP library doing this. We use princeXML and it's PHP wrapper for PDF generation. princeXML supports auto hyphenation.

Comment: I found this PHP library called phpHyphenator (http://yellowgreen.de/phphyphenator) . I'm gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a port of the TeX-Hyphenation to PHP. You can find it at [github](https://github.com/heiglandreas/Org_Heigl_Hyphenator). Currently I do not know of an adapter for Zend_PDF, but if the need arises, I might create one.